# PAHO Embedded C library Socket Recive implemantation

Tags: c, sockets, serialization, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to implement PAHO embedded C library to  custom device ( STM32F405/GPRS module )

My main problem is create custom recv() function , which will use source for buffer.

In PAHO library example, there is a transport_getdata() function. It handle transportation layer.
This is tranport_getdata() function.This example uses socket library from  which I don't have :(

```
int transport_getdata(unsigned char* buf, int count)
{
    int rc = recv(mysock, buf, count, 0);
    //printf("received %d bytes count %d\n", rc, (int)count);
    return rc;
}
```

To port library to my project, I need to write my own recv() function like  my_recv().

Standartd socket Recv() function description said,

Recv() will return length of message written to buffer from source.

So I try to write my_recv() for replace recv() , ( I don't need socket ID and FLAG)

```
int  my_recv(char *buf, int len){

    int i=0;

    if (len <= 0 )
        return -1;
    if (len > BUF_MAX)
        len=BUF_MAX - 2;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++){

        *buf=serial_buffer[0];
        *buf++;
        //shift one byte buffer to left
        memmove(serial_buffer, serial_buffer+1,(BUF_MAX-1)*sizeof(*serial_buffer));
        interrupt_pointer--; // After one byte shift, reduce serial interrupt pointer.
    }
    return i;
}
```

Handling TCP incoming data, I have a serial/TCP transparent connection over GPRS module.
I used interrupt to read every bytes from serial and all incoming bytes written on serial_buffer.

```
void USART1_IRQHandler(void){

    int byte;

    if (USART_GetITStatus(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE) != RESET) // Received characters modify string
    {
            byte= USART_ReceiveData(USART1);

    }

    serial_buffer[interrupt_pointer]=byte;
    interrupt_pointer++;
    if(interrupt_pointer==BUF_MAX){
        interrupt_pointer=0;
        memset(serial_buffer,0,BUF_MAX);
    }

}
```

For simple test, I send "1234567890" from over TCP socket,

simple test code is

```
while(strlen(serial_buffer)>0){

    delay_ms(1000);
    printf("%s\r\n",serial_buffer);
    my_recv(buf,3);
    printf("%s\r\n",buf);
    printf("%s\r\n",serial_buffer);
}
```

My system out is,

```
1234567890 // All TCP data received
123        // getting 3 bytes from buffer
4567890    // remaining bytes
```

I'm not sure I understand recv() function well.
This is output is alright.

Couse still I cant handle MQTT package with PAHO library.

Comment: It seems your `my_recv` function does not block or verify that there are incoming data to read, nor does it verify how much data you have available in your `serial_buffer`. You'll somehow have to make it wait until there actually are some data available in `serial_buffer`, and read only the data that is present there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with MQTT, but I would advise you to use the volatile type for your buffer. This way, compiler will not optimize it as a standard variable.

```
volatile unsigned char serial_buffer[512];
```

How does your transport function bahave?

Comment: I try it with volatile buffer, but its same. I think ,  After I read bytes from buffer, I  have to rolling it left.. Couse when  I copied recived bytes, my buffer still has recived bytes, next time I read same bytes